# swipe delete reappears item in favorite tab

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

So I'm trying to implement a swipe delete of my favorite items off the favorites tab. The swipe implementation works but when I go back to the Favorites Tab, the item deleted reappears. I'm using core data and I know it is not deleting it from core data but not sure how to fix it. This is my file for the favorites tab:

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavAnimeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var favorites = [NSManagedObject]()
    var numAnime = 0
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    //loads every time view appears
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        //1
        guard let appDelegate =
                UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //2
        let fetchRequest =
            NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Favorite")
        //3
        do {
            favorites = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favorites.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:  "FavTableViewCell") as! FavTableViewCell
        
        let favAnime = favorites[indexPath.row]
        cell.favtitleLabel.text = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "title") as? String
        cell.favsumLabel.text = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "synopsis") as? String
        if let poster = favAnime.value(forKey: "poster") as? String{
            let posterUrl = URL(string: poster)!
            cell.favposterView.af.setImage(withURL: posterUrl)

        }
        
        return cell
    }
    //MARK: Delete favorite items
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            favorites.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }
    
}
```

if any can help that be great

Answer (score 1):

The changes (in this case `Delete`) wont be seen affected until you save the state of the `NSManagedObjectContext`, Helpfully, managed object context has a matching **delete()** method that will delete any object regardless of its type or location in the object graph. Once an object has been deleted from the context, we can then call **saveContext()** to write that change back to the persistent store so that the change is permanent.

```
do {
  try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch (let error) {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Remember:** you must call **saveContext()** whenever you want your changes to persist.

I Hope I Helped!

[Core Data | nsmanagedobjectcontext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)

Comment: When i added this, I get an error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value 
for the line try managedObjectContext.save()
what does this mean and how to fix?

Comment: This means your managedObjectContext was deallocated before you used, try making a `strong` reference from your AppDelegate to this managedObjectContext to keep it existing.

(code refence only)

`
AppDelegate {
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

  func didFinishLaunching(withOptions: [options]) {
   //...
  self.managedObjectContext = persistanceContainer.viewConext
  }
}
`

Or check carefully your persistance container creation, debug it to see if it exists after your set up.

Answer (score 0):

Delete from CoreData

```
   func deleteParticularRecord(id:String){
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
           // use predicate for delete particular record from coredata.
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "EnitityName")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = '\(id)'")
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let objects = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for obj in objects {
                context.delete(obj as! NSManagedObject)
            }
            do {
                try context.save() // <- remember to put this :)
            } catch {
                // Do something... fatalerror
            }
        }
    // Call 
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            favorites.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            // use id or object id
            deleteParticularRecord(id: "_Id_")
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }
```

// Hope its works :)